# How to assertRaises a django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist exception?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to assert in a test that a statement raises this exception however it appears that it is impossible to import said exception. This does not work for example:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from CarPooling.views import login, logout
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from CarPooling.models import AccountActivationToken
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import DoesNotExist

class LoginViewTests(APITestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        url = '/api/token/'
        data = {'email': 'up20@fe.up.pt', 'password': 'testpassword'}
        user = create_user('joao', 'testpassword', 'up20@fe.up.pt')
        user = User.objects.get()
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()                     
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')       
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['token'], Token.objects.get(user=user).key)
        data = {'email': 'up20@fe.up.pt', 'password': 'tsubasaolivesr'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')       
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        data = {'email': 'up20@fe.up.pt', 'password': 'tsubasaolivesr'}
        self.assertRaises(models.DoesNotExist, self.client.post(url, data, format='json'))
```

The test fails complaining that exception django.auth.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist was invoked, even though I explicitly am asserting it is supposed to happen.

Comment: What happens if you change the `self.assertRaises(models.DoesNotExist,` to `self.assertRaises(DoesNotExist,` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're testing at the wrong level. Using the client to post to a view would never raise a Django exception; even if that exception is not caught within your view itself, which it almost certainly is, it would definitely be caught by the Django error middleware, and presented to the client as a 500 error.

So if you're really not catching that exception you can check that the result from the post has status 500; otherwise you need to check for whatever message you are showing to the user that the model does not exist.

Comment: But since the exception is raised in the server, the test immediately fails. When I had the test expecting to receive a 500_BAD_REQUEST reply the test would fail due to the exception in the server anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the traceback you receive on running the test.